# Looking for examples on how GIS techniques facilitate utility surveying and management

Tags: utility-network

Anyone get some ideas about the interface between underground utility and GIS? Utility surveying is quite a new topic to me and I want some examples on how GIS techniques facilitate utility surveying and management.

Comment: I'm not experienced in utility management, so just my few cents to this. It's simple to store survey data to utilities together with management data in a spatial database (it doesn't really matter if your company uses database vendor A or B). What counts more is the interface to integrate into your business cases. There are plenty of turnkey solutions for this, I think Autodesk (http://www.autodesk.com/industry/civil-infrastructure/utility-telecom-infrastructure) and GE Smallworld (http://www.gedigitalenergy.com/newsletter/june_2011/Industry_News/smallworld_assetmagmt.htm) should be evaluated.