# Gas Utility Routing software in open source or algorithm

Tags: open-source-gis, routing, topology, software-recommendations, utility-network

**objectives :** To make a web application for gas utility that can perform upstream and downstream

I have googled a lot but cannot find any Gas utility routing in open source. what i have is data for gas pipes as line and gas fittings as point .

Is there any open source software or algorithm that can help me ?

Comment: pretty much any routing application or library will do it if you have suitable topology

Comment: PolyGeo, can you please  explain why its too broad ?  and how can i narrow it ?

Comment: @simplexio pgrouting can work ? is it possible to simulate the valve close scenario using pgrouting ?

Comment: PolyGeo, a little similar question, in fact much broader than mine  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/56812/looking-for-examples-on-how-gis-techniques-facilitate-utility-surveying-and-mana?rq=1

Comment: Neither question looks like a borderline case. They are fine for asking in the [GIS Chat Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/939/gis) or with work perhaps on [softwarerecs.se] Stack Exchange. I am in transit so will come back with more advice.

Comment: I don't know about gis chat room . i will search and try there . thanks for direction.

Comment: Your question seems to be "Is there any open source software or algorithm that can help me ... To make a web application for gas utility that can perform upstream and downstream"?  To be suitable for our focussed Q&A format we need you to try and narrow this to something that you have tried and where you are stuck.  If you have not yet installed anything then you can interpret what you have tried as describing the precise research undertaken to try and achieve a specific task like meeting the key requirement of your planned solution.